# How Get Array of ParseObject...?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I have this method to save a level:

> ```
> public void SaveLevel(string LevelName,List<CrossObject> Objs)
> {
>     Debug.Log("Save Level...");
>     ParseObject level = new ParseObject("LevelTest");
>     level["Name"] = LevelName;
>     List<ParseObject> savedList = new List<ParseObject>();
>     foreach (var crossObject in Objs)
>     {
>         var p = new ParseObject("LevelDataTest");
>         p["PositionX"] = crossObject.transform.localPosition.x;
>         p["PositionY"] = crossObject.transform.localPosition.y;
>         p["PositionZ"] = crossObject.transform.localPosition.z;
>         p["RotationX"] = crossObject.transform.localRotation.x;
>         p["RotationY"] = crossObject.transform.localRotation.y;
>         p["RotationZ"] = crossObject.transform.localRotation.z;
>         p["RotationW"] = crossObject.transform.localRotation.w;
>         savedList.Add(p);
>     }
>     level["Objects"] = savedList.ToArray();
>     level.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(t=> Debug.Log("Level Saved."));       
> }
> ```

When I go to parse the data, I see:

http://i.gyazo.com/17d0a8039105d6a38cd0f138733be8da.png

The data is OK. But when I try loading the data in unity3d ....

```
var load = ParseObject.GetQuery("LevelTest").WhereEqualTo("Name", LevelName);
load.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t=>{
if (t.IsFaulted)
{
    Debug.Log("Broke...");
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Loading!");
    ParseObject o = t.Result;          
    var aux = o.GetRelation<ParseObject>("Objects").Query.FindAsync();
    aux.ContinueWith(x => Debug.Log("Done!!!" + t.Result));//This is never called!}});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does t.IsFaulted end up being true? Does anything in the else branch execute?

Comment: Does console log contain any errors?

Comment: No , any error and t.isFaulted = False.